# return throws error in if statement

Tags: javascript

I have an `if` statement with `return`s in it that throw an error when executed.

```
var booleanStatement = true;

if ( booleanStatement ){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This should return true but it instead throws an error. How can I get this statement to return true?

Comment: It shouldn't throw, what's the error?

Comment: run on my side too. What is your error ?

Comment: Working https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/114/

Comment: `array[3]` only throws an error if `array` is `undefined`.  It does not cause an error if `array[3]` itself is `undefined`.

Comment: You could do this: `return  Array.isArray(array) && array[3] === 3;`.  You will then get `false` if either `array` itself is not an array or if `array[3] !== 3` and true, only if `array` is an array object and `array[3] === 3`.  That should not throw.  Note, you can return the result of a boolean expression directly, there is no need for an `if/else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function for using the statement [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

> The **`return`** statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, , 4, 5];

function x() {
    if (array[3] === 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(x());
```